# Troubleshooting php-fpm load problems

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

I'll start with a bit of a back-story, there's times during the day we're getting a couple thousand requests to our server over a small period of time. While this is happening it seems that something regarding PHP FPM goes wrong and we can't access any of the webpages served by nginx and as soon as we restart php it seems to be working fine again. PHP FPM hasn't really been changed, the settings are as follows:

```
    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 5
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3
    pm.max_requests = 0
    pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s
```

After many of those requests are processed we start seeing this error

```
    connect() to unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: *.*.*.*, server: *.com, request: "GET /* HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "*.com"
```

I'm not sure if I can provide any more information regarding errors, if you think I can, be sure to ask and I'll check any of the log files I can. My question is can the problem be in the PHP FPM config?

Answer (score -2):

increase your pm.max_children = 5 to max supported by your system
and decrease pm.process_idle_timeout = 10s to least